# LINQ implementation of LIKE across multiple LINQ providers

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-like

I am trying to develop a .NET implementation of a standard ([OGC 04-095](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/filter) for those interested) that defines a XML based language to query a geospatial data source. I am having fun (true) translating these queries into LINQ expressions so that I could virtually access any kind of source (provided there is a LINQ provider for it, of course).

As a requirement, I have to implement the LIKE operator. I know I could use the [SqlMethods.Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx) method, but this would restrict me to SQL data sources. The question is: is it possible to have an implementation that would work accross different providers?

What I have in mind right now would be:

- if the provider is LINQ to SQL, use the [SqlMethods.Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx) method (so that the query could run on the database).
- if not, provide my own (so that it would run in memory).

Of course, this scenario would only be possible if I could detect the type of the provider the LINQ expression will execute on. I don't even know if this is possible.

For example, the following XML would be part of the input query:

```
<ogc:PropertyIsLike>
    <ogc:PropertyName>myProperty</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>%SOMETHING%TO_SEARCH%</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:PropertyIsLike>
```

A simplified excerpt of the code interpreting this is:

```
using System.Data.Linq.SqlClient;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public interface IExpressionBuilder
{
    Expression CreateExpression(ExpressionBuilderParameters parameters);
}

partial class PropertyIsLike:
    IExpressionBuilder
{
    protected override Expression CreateExpression(ExpressionBuilderParameters parameters)
    {
        // Only works with the LINQ to SQL provider
        return Expression.Call(
            typeof(SqlMethods).GetMethod("Like", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }),
            ((IExpressionBuilder)PropertyName).CreateExpression(parameters),
            ((IExpressionBuilder)Literal).CreateExpression(parameters)
        );

        //TODO: if provider is not LINQ to SQL, provide client side implementation
        // LINQ provider detection possible?
    }
}
```

`ExpressionBuilderParameter` is a custom type that can be filled with any information that can be inferred from a source `IQueryable` instance.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you give an example of what exactly are you transforming your queries into? Code containing LINQ method calls with lambdas?

Comment: I have added an example. Hope it helps understand the question.

Comment: I suppose ``String.Contains()``, ``String.StartsWith()`` and ``String.EndsWith()`` are not enough in your scenario?

Comment: No. As you can see in the XML example, the input LIKE queries must have the full blown SQL LIKE capabilities. I think I'll use regular expressions for the client side implementation.

Comment: Good call. Bear in mind that alternative LINQ implementations will fail. LINQ to SQL is kind of obsolete too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a lambda and regex would be cross provider and less code clutter.